# How to make onenote translate the zotero app url as a hyperlink rather than plaintext

Tags: windows, microsoft-onenote, hyperlink, zotero

I use onenote for note taking and zotero for reference management, so I usually make a hyper link in onenote pages with zotero APP URI for rapid redirection to the target item in zotero. Zotero APP URI is a "`zotero://select/library/items/V74C3DEA`"-like string. It is supposed to be translated as a clickable hyperlink; however, it fails in all my cases. I have to  produce such hyperlink with the ctrl+k dialog manually. It is really tiring.

Here is my question: How can I make any configurations to have onenote translate the `zotero://xx` URI correctly? Or is there any method that help me generate a pastable hyperlink with a fixed label and the copied zotero URI? It is a easy task in markdown by generating a string '`[fixed_label](zotero://xx)`' with autohotkey script, but in onenote I can't even find a clue. I wish someone will show me a practical solution. I am using win 10 Pro, currently 1903, but the issue appears in any of the earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are already doing can be accomplished by a sequence of keystrokes:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (open hyperlink window)
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (move focus to *Address* field)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste Zotero hyperlink from clipboard)
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd> (close hyperlink window)

Using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) you can create a macro to send these keystrokes for you, for example when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>:

```
^!v::Send ^k!e^v{Enter}
```

Optionally you can limit the shortcut only to OneNote application using [#IfWinActive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive.
The code with added `#IfWinActive` then looks like:

```
#IfWinActive - OneNote
^!v::Send ^k!e^v{Enter}
#IfWinActive
```